# Reverse an Array without using reverse Function and other array the same array to be reverse all elements in the same array. size fix

Tags: arrays, reverse

//      I am tring but cant do it

```
    int[] arr = {1,3,4,2,5,6};
    int n = arr.length,x = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) {
        x++;
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

//try this:

public class reverseArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int arr[] = new int[] { 1,3,4,2,5,6 };

    System.out.print("Original array: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");

    }

    // method #1: by using extra array

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Reversed array method 1: ");

    int j = 0;
    int revArr[] = new int[] { arr.length };

    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        revArr[j] = arr[i];
        System.out.print(revArr[j] + " ");

    }

    // method #2: without using extra array

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
        arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Reversed array method 2: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

}